# Variable change doesn't render in the view

Tags: state, render, svelte

The intention of the following code is to display a row if unique identifier of the row above is within the `rows` array. Why does Svelte update the view only after several clicks, in a seemingly random way?

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

        let rows = [
            {"name": "Alex", "id": "0"},
            {"name": "Steve", "id": "1"},
            {"name": "Mike", "id": "2"},
        ]; 
    
    let expandedRows = [];
    
    function toggleExpandRows(row_id_to_toggle) {
            console.log("Row to toggle:", row_id_to_toggle)
            console.log(expandedRows);
      if (expandedRows.includes(row_id_to_toggle)) {
                console.log(expandedRows, "includes", row_id_to_toggle)
        expandedRows = expandedRows.filter(expanded_row_id => expanded_row_id !== row_id_to_toggle)
      } else {
        expandedRows.push(row_id_to_toggle);
      }
    }

</script>

<div class="overflow-x-auto w-full">
  <table class="table table-compact w-full">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {#each rows as row (row.id)}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-xs" on:click={()=>toggleExpandRows(row.id)}>+/-</button>
          </td>
          <td class="min-w-[3rem] ">{row.name}</td>
        </tr>
            row.id: {JSON.stringify(row.id)}
        {#if expandedRows.includes(row.id)}
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">-</td>
          </tr>
        {/if}

      {/each}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Expanded: {JSON.stringify(expandedRows)}
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8feec08ccf1842c1b4a9e76db599930c?version=3.55.1)

Comment: In case it's okay to modify the data https://svelte.dev/repl/6b74ad0b9a21432f9e4f23ceedabb379?version=3.55.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactivity is based on assignments, which is why for arrays you also often see this pattern instead of `push`:

```js
array = [...array, item];
```

Comment: Thank you for explaning! I will be able to accept the answer in 1 minute. Would you be so kind and explore why Svelte still updates the view, but not straight away (usually after good dozen clicks)?

Comment: Half the actions invalidate the array (the assignment in the `if` branch), while the other half does not. So depending on the sequence you can get updates where nothing changed (click same twice) or you get changes because you clicked on another row an odd number of times. E.g. click first row once and second row twice and you will see the change in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `expandedRows.push(row_id_to_toggle)`, you should also assign `expandedRows`, so Svelte will know it has changed.
You can try:

```
.
.
.
else {
  expandedRows.push(row_id_to_toggle);
  expandedRows = expandedRows
}
```